# Solr Date Regex Query

Tags: regex, date, solr, expression

I want to use solr's regular expression capabilities to query a date field.
I'm trying to make a simple query like the following, but I get 0 results and no errors.
...?q=DATE:/200[0-9]-03-30T11\:58\:40Z/&fl=DATE

Here's some sample outputs:

```
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader">
<int name="status">0</int>
<int name="QTime">0</int>
<lst name="params">
<str name="fl">id,date</str>
<str name="q">date:/.*:.*/</str>
</lst>
</lst>
<result name="response" numFound="39" start="0">
<doc>
<str name="id">1362932537549-A17C9685</str>
<date name="date">2012-10-31T14:57:53Z</date>
</doc>
<doc>
<str name="id">1362932537549-AD280D59</str>
<date name="date">2012-10-25T09:57:53Z</date>
</doc>
<doc>
<str name="id">1362932537549-B091BE97</str>
<date name="date">2012-10-23T09:57:53Z</date>
</doc>
<doc>
<str name="id">1362932537549-B0D8341C</str>
<date name="date">2012-10-22T14:57:53Z</date>
</doc>
<doc>
<str name="id">1362932537549-40083ADB</str>
<date name="date">2010-08-12T14:33:00Z</date>
</doc>
<doc>
<str name="id">1362932537549-9CA68015</str>
<date name="date">2011-07-20T12:25:02Z</date>
</doc>
...

<response>
<lst name="responseHeader">
<int name="status">0</int>
<int name="QTime">8380</int>
<lst name="params">
<str name="fl">id,date</str>
<str name="q">date:/.*.*/</str>
</lst>
</lst>
<result name="response" numFound="1263" start="0">
<doc>
<str name="id">1362932537549-5A0DAFB7</str>
<date name="date">2010-08-12T14:31:00Z</date>
</doc>
<doc>
<str name="id">1362932537549-D712F1C71</str>
<date name="date">2011-12-01T13:23:53Z</date>
</doc>
<doc>
<str name="id">1362932537549-3FAA6BC</str>
<date name="date">2012-05-25T14:26:08Z</date>
</doc>
<doc>
<str name="id">1362932537549-C8A6B81F</str>
<date name="date">2010-08-12T14:25:00Z</date>
</doc>
<doc>
<str name="id">1362932537549-D712F1C8</str>
<date name="date">2011-12-01T13:23:53Z</date>
</doc>
...

<response>
<lst name="responseHeader">
<int name="status">0</int>
<int name="QTime">34443</int>
<lst name="params">
<str name="fl">id,date</str>
<str name="q">date:/.*0.*/</str>
</lst>
</lst>
<result name="response" numFound="65" start="0">
<doc>
<str name="id">1362932537549-A4BC013G</str>
<date name="date">2012-10-29T17:57:53Z</date>
</doc>
<doc>
<str name="id">1362932537549-862F708G</str>
<date name="date">2013-02-14T09:48:46Z</date>
</doc>
<doc>
<str name="id">1362932537549-B8A38A74</str>
<date name="date">2013-02-14T09:49:18Z</date>
</doc>
<doc>
<str name="id">1362932537549-D4BA90CD</str>
<date name="date">2007-10-09T21:53:34Z</date>
</doc>
<doc>
<str name="id">1362932537549-3028513F</str>
<date name="date">2011-06-24T20:30:22Z</date>
</doc>
```

Comment: If this helps, something like ...?q=text:/message(.*)?/&fl=id,text works and returns every document with the 'text' field set to message. For the date field when I try the following, I get 0 results: ...?q=date:/2013-03-30T15\:58\:4(.*)?/&fl=id,date

Comment: Start with a simpler expression like `?q=date:/.*/&fl=date`. If this doesn't work either, then it might be that `date` is not a `string` type that can be straightforwardly regex'ed.

Comment: ^ That works. I get back all of the records when I use ?q=date:/.*/&fl=date

Comment: Hm, what about `date:/.*:.*/`? I'm curious whether escaping the colon is messing things up.

Comment: That's weird! Would you edit the question and include a few output samples (keep it as raw as possible, exactly the way you see it) from each group: a few from the 1000, a few from the 30, and a few from the 20?

Comment: There are 1000 records that are returned with date:/.*/ but only 30 that are returned with date:/.*:.*/ and 20 with date:/.*-.*/ . All of the dates contain both ':' and '-'. Also I tried date:/.*0.*/ and not all of the records with a 0 were returned.

Comment: I think I know what's happening. Try one more thing for me? Do any of the following queries return results? `date:/.*_.*/`, `date:/.*,.*/`, and `date:/.*A.*/`.

Comment: None of those work. They all return around 20-30 results.

Comment: But they return results, right? I think what's happening is that `date` is not a `string` field, therefore when you search for characters like `:`, you're actually finding results that _happen_ to have those characters in their _encoded form_. That's why you get results even when you search for characters that clearly don't exist in the results, like `_`, `,`, and `A`. I don't think the `date` field is regexable.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you for all of the help. I really appreciate it. If you want to edit your answer with that comment, I'll accept it.

Comment: No problem. Sorry I don't know how the real solution (_e.g._ if there's a way to cast the date field into a string). But my answer has been edited. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex looks okay, but instead of escaping the colons, try URL-encoding the value:

```
?q=DATE%3A%2F200%5B0-9%5D-03-30T11%5C%3A58%5C%3A40Z%2F&fl=DATE
```

---

(Migrated from a comment on the question.)

**It seems it's not possible to regex a date field, directly at least.**

As you found, even the following queries `date:/.*_.*/`, `date:/.*,.*/`, and `date:/.*A.*/` return results, even though timestamps clearly have none of those characters. I think what's happening is that `date` is not a `string` field, therefore when you query for a character like `:`, you're actually finding results that *happen* to have that character amongst *encoded* (*e.g.* raw binary) data. (In layman's terms, imagine opening up binary data (like an executable file) in Notepad and searching for an ASCII character.)

This also explains why you're getting about the same number of results, 20 to 30, for all those queries: statistically speaking, regexing for a random ASCII character amongst binary (and other encoded) data should return about the same frequency of results.