# Solr, searching between times, ignoring dates

Tags: solr

lets say I have a log about opening bars:

```
{
    opened:       '2013-11-05T00:00:00Z',
    opened_start: '2013-11-05T12:00:00Z',
    opened_end:   '2013-11-05T14:00:00Z',
},
{
    opened:       '2013-15-05T00:00:00Z',
    opened_start: '2013-15-05T11:00:00Z',
    opened_end:   '2013-15-05T13:00:00Z',
},
{
    opened:       '2013-11-05T00:00:00Z',
    opened_start: '2013-11-05T18:00:00Z',
    opened_end:   '2013-11-05T19:00:00Z',
},
{
    opened:       '2013-11-12T00:00:00Z',
    opened_start: '2013-11-12T02:00:00Z',
    opened_end:   '2013-11-12T14:00:00Z',
}
```

now I only need the opened bars between 00:00:00 and 06:00:00. I have no influence about the structure, but it basically builds like this:

```
{
    opened:       'YMD000',
    opened_start: 'YMD02:00:00Z',
    opened_end:   'YMD14:00:00Z',
}
```

EDIT: I was thinking of substracting: opened_start - opened so I would get only times: 0000-00-00 02:00:00

Answer (score 1):

You can represent your bar opening range as a coordinate in XY space, with opening-hour being X and closing-hour being Y. Then, you can use range math to look for overlaps as per [Hoss's presentation](https://home.apache.org/~hossman/spatial-for-non-spatial-meetup-20130117/).

You can use custom UpdateRequestProcessor chain to manipulate your dates to convert that into that format. I think you probably only need to extract an hour, as that's your granularity.

Answer (score 0):

this was asked yesterday: [Solr, search only by time among datetime fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43582514/solr-search-only-by-time-among-datetime-fields/43584095#43584095)

The best and easiest thing is to just add another field, and add the time of opening there in the proper format to be easily queriable, any of the following will work:

1. just append all time numbers like: T13:00:00Z ==> 130000
2. use the number of seconds/minutes since midnight
3. use the number of seconds/minutes since X instant (like 2013-11-01T00:00:00Z) that is you absolute base time

Now, if you don't control the client side, you need to add the field from inside solr, the easiest is to do it with a copyField (see the link above), or with an UpdateRequestProcessor (much more work, not worth it).